# Al least one checkbox must be selected, with one error message

Tags: jquery, validation

PROBLEM is:
there should be only one message. like

```
 Invalid:
    Please select at least one!
```

but Errors are displayed as:

```
Invalid:
Please select at least one!
Please select at least one!
```

Here is code :
HTML:

```
<input id="contact" class="contact_class" type="checkbox" number="12121" name="contact[]">
<input id="contact" class="contact_class" type="checkbox" number="252525" name="contact[]">
```

Custom validation method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("contactcheck", function(value, elem, param) {
 return $(".contact_class:checked").length >= 1;
},"You must select at least one!");
```

validating form as :

```
$("#frmsend").validate({
        debug:false, onsubmit: true, onfocusout: false, onkeyup: false,
        rules: {
            'contact[]': {    contactcheck: true }
        },
        messages: {
            'contact[]': { contactcheck: "Please select at least one!"    }
        }
        ,showErrors: vError
        ,submitHandler: vSuccess
    });
```

Error function:

```
function vError(eM, eL) {
    if(eL.length===0) return;
    var arr=[];
    for(var err=0;err<eL.length;err++) {
            arr.push({ message: eL[err].message });
    }
    $("#showerrors").notification({caption: "Invalid:", messages: arr});
}
```

Comment: Use jQuery.inArray to make the error's array unique. Do let me know if you want me to modify your code using jQuery.inArray

Comment: Please edit @amarjeetkumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery.inArray to check duplicate error message. Below is you modified function.

```
function vError(eM, eL) {
 if(eL.length===0) return;
   var arr=[];
   var msgAlrdyAdded = [];
   for(var err=0;err<eL.length;err++) {
      if(jQuery.inArray( eL[err].message, msgAlrdyAdded )==-1){
         arr.push({ message: eL[err].message });
          msgAlrdyAdded.push(eL[err].message); 
      }

   }
    $("#showerrors").notification({caption: "Invalid:", messages: arr});
 }
```